# Python FIX API - no response at Logon

Tags: python, bitcoin, fix-protocol, algorithmic-trading, gdax-api

I've been trying to set up a connection to the FIX API for the GDAX crpyto exchange, but I can't seem to logon properly. I'm using the code below to generate the message:

```
import time
import simplefix
import socket
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4197))

API_KEY = "KEY_GOES_HERE"
PASSPHRASE = "PASSPHRASE_GOES_HERE"
API_SECRET = "SECRET_GOES_HERE"

seq_num = "1"
sendingTime = str(datetime.utcnow()).replace("-","").replace(" ", "-")[:-3]
rawSig = "\x01".join([sendingTime, "A", seq_num, API_KEY, "Coinbase", PASSPHRASE]).encode("utf-8")

hmac_key  = base64.b64decode(API_SECRET)
signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, rawSig, hashlib.sha256)
sign_b64  = base64.b64encode(signature.digest()).decode()

msg = simplefix.FixMessage()

msg.append_pair(8, "FIX.4.2")
msg.append_pair(35, "A")
msg.append_pair(49, API_KEY)
msg.append_pair(52, sendingTime)
msg.append_pair(56, "Coinbase")
msg.append_pair(98, "0")
msg.append_pair(108, "30")
msg.append_pair(554, PASSPHRASE)
msg.append_pair(96, sign_b64)
msg.append_pair(8013, "Y")

print(msg.encode())
s.sendall(msg.encode("ascii"))
print(s.recv(4096))
```

And I'm getting 0 bytes of response from the server. As far as I can tell, the stunnel is working properly (connects and validates certificates successfully, but disconnects after sending my logon message).

Have just tried with a newly generated API key, passphrase and secret but to no avail.

For reference, I was working from the question asked here: [How to send FIX logon message with Python to GDAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110454/how-to-send-fix-logon-message-with-python-to-gdax) but I'm not allowed to comment there.

If anyone has any ideas, would be appreciated. Below is an example of the fix message generated, passwords removed in post:

```
8=FIX.4.2\x019=161\x0135=A\x0149=[KEY_REMOVED]\x0152=20180113-18:24:07.889\x0156=Coinbase\x0198=0\x01108=30\x01554=[PASSPHRASE_REMOVED]\x0196=jueSJHoSNQM2BOCN3KM0mgB2/9tXpICbg4amqDKc2wY=\x018013=Y\x0110=053\x01
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. From what I can gather, to connect to the FIX API, you have to connect not to the local host but to GDAX with `s.connect(("fix.gdax.com", 4198))`. Please let me know if that does anything for you.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @ArdaArslan yeah that kind of looks like the obvious issue. He’s trying to connect to himself. I thought maybe he was running a local engine like quickfix at first. But this is the very first night that I am learning about the FIX API protocol, so I’m going to try this out myself with simplefix in the next few days. I will probably definitely be reporting back to this thread since it’s one of the only ones I can find for support so far.