# Coinbase FIX Logon signature

Tags: encryption, quickfix, coinbase-api, fix-protocol

Problem: I cannot properly encode signature, according to https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/docs/messages . No matter what I'm doing, I'm getting "Invalid signature" rejection.

I'm using QuickFix FIX engine, and my code is written in C++. Signature calculation code provided below. b64_encode and hmac_sha256 are based on OpenSSL functions and were verified in another parts of application, so they are expected to be working correctly (unless Coinbase actually expects another kind of encryption).

```
const auto join_elem = '\x01';
auto data_to_encrypt =
    header.getField(FIX::FIELD::SendingTime) + join_elem +
    "A" + join_elem +
    header.getField(FIX::FIELD::MsgSeqNum) + join_elem +
    header.getField(FIX::FIELD::SenderCompID) + join_elem +
    header.getField(FIX::FIELD::TargetCompID) + join_elem +
    api_password;

std::vector<unsigned char> prehash(data_to_encrypt.begin(), data_to_encrypt.end());
auto signature_value = b64_encode(hmac_sha256(data, b64_decode(secret)));
```

As I'm using sandbox account, it is safe to share all the keys for the case if someone could verify calculation.
api_password=uxu3qgheh0e
SenderCompID=b0744eb59b6951d7955e5e5aaed3709f
secret=T/SabUfV28tyVDVv5AsMuk5oqDFdvGwQrfc6f1/RnatGfpAcpAMMRzjfON8nqoL6bAsUI6jkN9gWEX809z1iiA==

Complete logon example:
8=FIX.4.2|9=172|35=A|34=1|49=b0744eb59b6951d7955e5e5aaed3709f|52=20211112-16:45:45.856|56=Coinbase|96=6fsAC9XcV9Fm4II89s8VZgm4wmeiNclr3YY+mNTbMdo=|98=0|108=30|141=Y|554=uxu3qgheh0e|8013=Y|10=253|
And the following rejection:
8=FIX.4.2|9=128|35=3|34=1|49=Coinbase|52=20211112-16:45:46.985|56=b0744eb59b6951d7955e5e5aaed3709f|45=1|58=invalid signature|371=96|372=A|373=5|10=216|

Unfortunately, support replied with "Coinbase will only offer self-help customer support in your region", so I have to ask for help here. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the other questions on StackOverflow dealing with similar problems?

Comment: @ChristophJohn sure, I checked that. The most similar I found was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110454/how-to-send-fix-logon-message-with-python-to-gdax-coinbase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a day of research, I finally found the issue. As I first step, I found working library written in NodeJS (it was easier to use it for testing) to ensure my credentials are working. Then I added console prints to NodeJS lib to see what values are calculated on the each step of signature making. Then I used the same values for my code and finally came to base64 decoding function, which I used to "decode" secret key. It was the following:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> b64_decode(const std::string& data) {
    BIO* b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

    BIO* bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)data.c_str(), data.length());
    bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

    std::vector<unsigned char> output(data.length());
    int decoded_size = BIO_read(bmem, output.data(), output.size());
    BIO_free_all(bmem);

    return output;
}
```

This function appears to be incorrect if source data size not equal to output size, as I forgot to resize output according to actual length, and it was containing extra zeroes which caused decoded secret key to be incorrect. I.e. I just needed to add resize:

```
if (output.size() > decoded_size) {
    output.resize(decoded_size);
}
```